# Failed installing Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, npx

Hi I'm trying to create a Nuxt project using `npx` and this is what I get:

```
$ npx create-nuxt-app nuxt-prop
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Faturachman'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:77:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:98:27)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)
Install for create-nuxt-app@latest failed with code 7
```

Can anyone help me what's wrong? I can't seem to find the solution anywhere :/

Comment: Seems like this is error with `npx`, [GitHub issue](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/100).

Answer (score 4):

the problem would be seem because of spacing in the username, so i managed to fix it by running cmd as administrator and

`npm config set cache "C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global`

change the spacing with "~1"